# how do I take out index and not all of the char in a string?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

I want to instruct the computer so that if a character in string 'a' is also a character in string 'b', to remove that character (just that one character), however what the code below is doing is removing all of the same characters from the string at one go. Any help?

I have tried to use a[I] and b[I] to replace the index for each loop, but then the code below needs to be changed entirely, because I can no longer do 'for I in a' and 'if I in b', as I need integer references for the 'i's.

e.g. a = "askhfidshf"
b = "fhsdhfojej"

```
def permutation_checker(a,b):
    if a==b:
        print("a is a permutation of b")

    if a != b:
        while a and b:
            for i in a:
                if i in b:
                    new_a = a.replace(i,"")
                    print(new_a)
                    a = new_a
                    new_b = b.replace(i,"")
                    print(new_b)
                    b =new_b

                    if (a=="") and b == "":
                        print("a is a permutation of b")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`replace` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) takes a parameter which specifies how many occurrences shall be replaced. By default it will replace all.

> ```
> str.replace(old, new[, count])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider string manipulation a little complicated to do with so, I would recommend converting it into an array because you can utilize the index method and your challenge for getting an integer reference will be solved. Take a look at the code I came up with.

```
def permutation_checker(a, b):
    array_a = [i for i in a] # converting the string to an array
    array_b = [i for i in b] # converting the string to an array

    for i in range(len(array_a )):
        if array_a[i] in array_b:
            char_index = array_b.index(array_a[i]) # getting the first index of the value array_a[i] within array_b
            array_b[char_index] = ''

    if array_b == [''] * len(b):
        print(f'{a} is a permutation of {b}')
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In fact I work better with arrays, and this was my first thought but I had the same issue of the integer. But I now see how your solution fixed this! Thanks